# JSON.parse exptected ',' or '}' Any idea? both don't work

Tags: javascript, json

Both the JSON.parse and eval functions are erroring. I validated the JSON using http://jsonlint.com/ any idea what to do ?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

var obj = JSON.parse('{ "defaults": { "recordtext": "View", "emptyrecords": "No records to view", "loadtext": "Loading...", "pgtext": "Page" }, "search": { "caption": "Search...", "Find": "Find", "Reset": "Reset", "odata": [ "equal", "not equal", "less", "less or equal", "greater", "greater or equal", "begins with", "does not begin with", "is in", "is not in", "ends with", "does not end with", "contains", "does not contain" ], "groupOps": [ { "op": "AND", "text": "all" }, { "op": "OR", "text": "any" } ], "matchText": " match", "rulesText": " rules" }, "edit": { "addCaption": "Add Record", "editCaption": "Edit Record", "bSubmit": "Submit", "bCancel": "Cancel", "bClose": "Close", "saveData": "Data has been changed! Save changes?", "bYes": "Yes", "bNo": "No", "bExit": "Cancel", "msg": { "required": "Field is required", "number": "Please, enter valid number", "minValue": "value must be greater than or equal to ", "maxValue": "value must be less than or equal to", "email": "is not a valid e-mail", "integer": "Please, enter valid integer value", "date": "Please, enter valid date value", "url": "is not a valid URL. Prefix required (\"http://\" or \"https://\")", "nodefined": " is not defined!", "novalue": " return value is required!", "customarray": "Custom function should return array!", "customfcheck": "Custom function should be present in case of custom checking!" } }, "view": { "caption": "View Record", "bClose": "Close" }, "del": { "caption": "Delete", "msg": "Delete selected record(s)?", "bSubmit": "Delete", "bCancel": "Cancel" }, "nav": { "edittext": "", "edittitle": "Edit selected row", "addtext": "", "addtitle": "Add new row", "deltext": "", "deltitle": "Delete selected row", "searchtext": "", "searchtitle": "Find records", "refreshtext": "", "refreshtitle": "Reload Grid", "alertcap": "Warning", "alerttext": "Please, select row", "viewtext": "", "viewtitle": "View selected row" }, "col": { "caption": "Select columns", "bSubmit": "Ok", "bCancel": "Cancel" }, "errors": { "errcap": "Error", "nourl": "No url is set", "norecords": "No records to process", "model": "Length of colNames <> colModel!" }, "formatter": { "integer": { "thousandsSeparator": " ", "defaultValue": "0" }, "number": { "decimalSeparator": ".", "thousandsSeparator": " ", "decimalPlaces": 2, "defaultValue": "0.00" }, "currency": { "decimalSeparator": ".", "thousandsSeparator": " ", "decimalPlaces": 2, "prefix": "", "suffix": "", "defaultValue": "0.00" }, "date": { "dayNames": [ "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thr", "Fri", "Sat", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" ], "monthNames": [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ], "AmPm": [ "am", "pm", "AM", "PM" ], "srcformat": "Y-m-d", "newformat": "m/d/Y", "masks": { "ISO8601Long": "Y-m-d H:i:s", "ISO8601Short": "Y-m-d", "ShortDate": "n/j/Y", "LongDate": "l, F d, Y", "FullDateTime": "l, F d, Y g:i:s A", "MonthDay": "F d", "ShortTime": "g:i A", "LongTime": "g:i:s A", "SortableDateTime": "Y-m-d\\TH:i:s", "UniversalSortableDateTime": "Y-m-d H:i:sO", "YearMonth": "F, Y" }, "reformatAfterEdit": false }, "baseLinkUrl": "", "showAction": "", "target": "", "checkbox": { "disabled": true }, "idName": "id" }, "emptyrecords": "test" }');
var obj2 = eval ( '(' + '{ "defaults": { "recordtext": "View", "emptyrecords": "No records to view", "loadtext": "Loading...", "pgtext": "Page" }, "search": { "caption": "Search...", "Find": "Find", "Reset": "Reset", "odata": [ "equal", "not equal", "less", "less or equal", "greater", "greater or equal", "begins with", "does not begin with", "is in", "is not in", "ends with", "does not end with", "contains", "does not contain" ], "groupOps": [ { "op": "AND", "text": "all" }, { "op": "OR", "text": "any" } ], "matchText": " match", "rulesText": " rules" }, "edit": { "addCaption": "Add Record", "editCaption": "Edit Record", "bSubmit": "Submit", "bCancel": "Cancel", "bClose": "Close", "saveData": "Data has been changed! Save changes?", "bYes": "Yes", "bNo": "No", "bExit": "Cancel", "msg": { "required": "Field is required", "number": "Please, enter valid number", "minValue": "value must be greater than or equal to ", "maxValue": "value must be less than or equal to", "email": "is not a valid e-mail", "integer": "Please, enter valid integer value", "date": "Please, enter valid date value", "url": "is not a valid URL. Prefix required (\"http://\" or \"https://\")", "nodefined": " is not defined!", "novalue": " return value is required!", "customarray": "Custom function should return array!", "customfcheck": "Custom function should be present in case of custom checking!" } }, "view": { "caption": "View Record", "bClose": "Close" }, "del": { "caption": "Delete", "msg": "Delete selected record(s)?", "bSubmit": "Delete", "bCancel": "Cancel" }, "nav": { "edittext": "", "edittitle": "Edit selected row", "addtext": "", "addtitle": "Add new row", "deltext": "", "deltitle": "Delete selected row", "searchtext": "", "searchtitle": "Find records", "refreshtext": "", "refreshtitle": "Reload Grid", "alertcap": "Warning", "alerttext": "Please, select row", "viewtext": "", "viewtitle": "View selected row" }, "col": { "caption": "Select columns", "bSubmit": "Ok", "bCancel": "Cancel" }, "errors": { "errcap": "Error", "nourl": "No url is set", "norecords": "No records to process", "model": "Length of colNames <> colModel!" }, "formatter": { "integer": { "thousandsSeparator": " ", "defaultValue": "0" }, "number": { "decimalSeparator": ".", "thousandsSeparator": " ", "decimalPlaces": 2, "defaultValue": "0.00" }, "currency": { "decimalSeparator": ".", "thousandsSeparator": " ", "decimalPlaces": 2, "prefix": "", "suffix": "", "defaultValue": "0.00" }, "date": { "dayNames": [ "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thr", "Fri", "Sat", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" ], "monthNames": [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ], "AmPm": [ "am", "pm", "AM", "PM" ], "srcformat": "Y-m-d", "newformat": "m/d/Y", "masks": { "ISO8601Long": "Y-m-d H:i:s", "ISO8601Short": "Y-m-d", "ShortDate": "n/j/Y", "LongDate": "l, F d, Y", "FullDateTime": "l, F d, Y g:i:s A", "MonthDay": "F d", "ShortTime": "g:i A", "LongTime": "g:i:s A", "SortableDateTime": "Y-m-d\\TH:i:s", "UniversalSortableDateTime": "Y-m-d H:i:sO", "YearMonth": "F, Y" }, "reformatAfterEdit": false }, "baseLinkUrl": "", "showAction": "", "target": "", "checkbox": { "disabled": true }, "idName": "id" }, "emptyrecords": "test" }' + ')');

</script>
```

Comment: I think you need to escape the colons.

Comment: @pst i checked this using jsonlint. It is a says "Valid JSON".  I have also mentioned that on my question.

Comment: @David I dont see that anywhere? here is the IE documentation for this stuff http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836466%28v=VS.94%29.aspx ?

Comment: @user1596914 Which browser(s) does this occur on? Create a jsfiddle test-case?

Answer (score 4):

You are not escaping the quotes properly you need another back slash;

This is wrong;

```
JSON.parse('{ "fails" : "\"http://\" or \"https://\"" }')
```

It should be like this;

```
JSON.parse('{ "passes" : "\\"http://\\" or \\"https://\\"" }')
```

Comment: In general with such a large JSON structure try to break it down into smaller chunks and test those until you isolate the part that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

When something is valid JSON, it basically means that you can write this:

```
var xx = <that-thing-you-validated>;
```

However, `JSON.parse()` expects a JSON formatted string, which is not the same. Observe:

```
var yy = {text: "hello \"world\""};
console.log(JSON.stringify(yy));
// output: "{"text":"hello \"world\""}"
```

Okay, so let's copy/paste that, and replace the outer double quotes with single quotes (because we don't want to escape the double quotes inside).

```
console.log('{"text":"hello \"world\""}');
// output: {"text":"hello "world""}
```

Woah, what happened to the backslashes?! **To create a string literal in JavaScript that contains a backslash, that too needs to be escaped**:

```
console.log('{"text":"hello \\"world\\""}');
// output: {"text":"hello \"world\""}
```

Does it work now?

```
JSON.parse('{"text":"hello \\"world\\""}');
// output: Object
```

Yes! :)